# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop

I've checked other SO questions like this but none seem to apply.

I have my Service class:

```
package com.test.demo.service;

import com.test.demo.controller.Controller2;
import com.test.demo.model.SettlementTransaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestService {

    public Controller2.AcctDetails testAcctDeets(Transaction transaction){
```

and my aspect:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.test.demo.service.TestService.testAcctDeets(..))", returning = "response")
public void interceptRequest(Controller2.AcctDetails response, JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
        if (arg instanceof String)
            System.out.println("  request = " + arg);
    }
    System.out.println("  response = " + response.toString());
}
```

but I keep getting the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to reverse the order of advice method parameters. It should be `(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint , Controller2.AcctDetails response)`

Comment: Sigh. You're a lifesaver. Can't believe I wasted so much time on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reference documentation : [Access to the Current](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-the-joinpoint)

> Any advice method may declare, as its first parameter, a parameter of
>   type `org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint` (note that around advice is required
>   to declare a first parameter of type `ProceedingJoinPoint`, which is a
>   subclass of `JoinPoint`

This is documented as continuation to the topic **Advice Parameters** which has reference to this : *Spring offers fully typed advice, meaning that you declare the parameters you need in the advice signature (as we saw earlier for the returning and throwing examples)*.

When read together , when passing advice parameters and the advice method also has `JointPoint` or any of its subclas as another parameter , the latter should be declared as the first parameter.

So in this case , the valid method signature would be

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.test.demo.service.TestService.testAcctDeets(..))", returning = "response")
public void interceptRequest(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Controller2.AcctDetails response) {
    // ..
}
```